# What is a purpose of "all:" in atmega bootloader's makefile?

Tags: makefile

Here is a peace of code of `makefile`:

```
OBJCOPY        = avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP        = avr-objdump

all:

lilypad: TARGET = lilypad
lilypad: CFLAGS += '-DMAX_TIME_COUNT=F_CPU>>1' '-DNUM_LED_FLASHES=3'
```

Executing `$ make all` returns:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Why did somebody put a target `all` without prerequisites?

Comment: Looks like a crude way to avoid ill effects when a newcomer or busy distracted developer types just `make` without examining the makefine first. It would arguably be friendlier to print an explicit warning, but that's probably why the makefile author set it up this way.

Comment: @tripleee, that makes sense. Thanks